# How to get selected option (Selenium & Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, find, element

I have a problem because I would like to get the selected option name: Option3 in this case. I want to use assert to check if value is selected correctly in this case. You can see a part of my page below:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rich-toolbar " id="mainMenuToolbar" width="100%">
   <tbody>
    <tr valign="middle">
     <td class="rich-toolbar-item  " style=";">
      <form id="substituteForm" name="name" method="post" action="http://homepage/home.seam" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
       <select name="substituteForm:j_id158" size="1" onchange="document.getElementById(&#39;substituteForm:substituteSubmit&#39;).click();">
        <option value="0">Option0</option>
        <option value="1">Option2</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Option3</option>
       </select>
      </form>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

I used DevTool to copy XPath and I wrote a code:

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*   [@id='substituteForm']/select"))
```

and I have error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='substituteForm']/select
```

I tried many XPath combinations and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to be timing issue, but not `XPath`

Try to use below code to wait until target `select` element appear in `DOM`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

select = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='substituteForm']/select")))
select.click()
selected_option = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//option[@selected='selected']")))
assert selected_option.text == "Option3"
```